# Question about the method of dynamic optimization.

Tags: optimization, operations-research, dynamic-programming

My question is a bit general, but it is more common in solving dynamic optimization. I think dynamic optimization is more like a way of solving problems. We first need to divide the problem into several stages. My question is

> How can we know or prove the answer is independent of the way we divide the stages?

To be specific, when solving a resource distribution problem. Like allocating 5 scientists to 3 countries($A, B, C$), How can I know that it does not matter whether we choose $A$ country to be the first stage or $B$ be the first or $C$?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you solve your problem twice, once using the ordering A-B-C and again using the ordering B-A-C, and suppose that the solution to the A-B-C version has a better objective value than the solution to the B-A-C version. Assuming that the problem is amenable to dynamic programming (not every problem is), you should be able to demonstrate that the solution to the A-B-C version is also a feasible solution to the B-A-C version, *with the same objective value*, contradicting the assumption that the optimal solution to B-A-C is inferior to the optimal solution to A-B-C.

Comment: I think I do not get you properly. For a specific problem when using the ordering A-B_C, I can get an answer. Using the ordering B-A-C -If I try- I can get the same answer. So you mean I should iterate all the possible orderings? It is a bit tedious.

Comment: No, what I was outlining is a proof that the ordering of the stages does not matter in terms of whether an optimal solution is found. The ordering of the stages can affect how easy it is to solve the problem. DP is equivalent to finding a shortest path through a directed graph, and choosing a "bad" ordering of stages can increase the size of that graph (number of nodes/arcs), but any ordering should result in an optimal solution.

Comment: I would appreciate it if you give me detailed proof or recommend some materials for referring.